# Scalable single query that pulls rows with multple unique primary ids

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

So I've got ratings for items by users in a mysql database, and I was wondering whats the best way to check if a list of items has rated by a user.

1. I could pull all the items a user has ever rated in a single query and then go through that set looking for items in my list.
2. The other way would be to use a single query to check for each item to see if its been rated.

The first way has the benefit of using a single query, the second one doesn't require me to pull all items a user has ever rated. Which one is better? I'm new to sql so I'm not really sure how bad query overhead is. Additionally, if you have better suggestions, feel free to give them.

As requested, here is an example table.

```
CREATE TABLE ratings (
  user id INT NOT NULL, 
  item_id INT NOT NULL, 
  rating INT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset, CREATE TABLE, INSERT etc as I can't tell if what you want to do is a simple GROUP BY query

Comment: I think this is a SO question. Anybody else agree?

Comment: Ok, in keeping with the community agreement found here: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators/25#25 and the fact that my move suggestion got upvoted I'm pushing this over to SO. That's a better site for "I'm new to SQL" than this site is intended to be. :\

Comment: Is the 'list of items' actually in the database? Or just in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a single query for each item, you would be scanning/seeking `ratings` so many times how many items you've got. Maybe I'm missing something, but so far I can't see how it's better than using one query to check all the items.

Besides, operating on sets is actually what SQL is best fit for, isn't it?

So here's an example query for checking all the list of items.

```
SELECT
  il.item_id,
  CASE
    WHEN r.item_id IS NULL THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
  END AS IsRated
FROM itemlist il
  LEFT JOIN ratings r ON il.item_id = r.item_id
                     AND rating > 0
                     AND user = @user
```

It is assumed that one user can only rate one item once, so I'm not trying to suppress duplicates here.